# What do the red and blue tiles on the map mean?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In the Fortress mode, I have noticed that there are red and blue tiles present on the overview map. Moreover, the red tiles have a tendency to move around. However, when I zoom in on their location, I am unable to find anything special. I have searched and I have not been able to find any information about these tiles.

This is what I am talking about:

[image: Image showing the red and blue tiles on the map]

I am very curious now, what do these colored tiles mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Red is the location of creatures and monsters, the red meaning "potentially dwarf-scaring or -mauling". Blue is the location of your dwarfs.

The colour ignores z-levels of air, so if there are fliers you'll have to hunt through the elevations to find out what the map is indicating. Also note that there is no consistent size relationship between you normal view and the map, so you might be looking at multiple map-squares or just part of one, depending on your screen size and the size of the embark area.

Comment: The coloured squares can also indicate the presence of creatures deep underground. Perhaps deeper than you have yet dug.

Comment: I haven't found that to be the case.